# Database/Object/Query Change Notification in Sybase

Tags: sybase

Oracle has CQN or Change Notification feature that allows a client to register a callback should a query/object changes in database. Is there any similar function feature in Sybase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct callback mechanism possible. But what you could do is use a trigger to send a UDP message with the `syb_sendmsg()`. This can be sent to any IP adddress reachable from the Sybase server.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't point which version of Sybase you use. ASE 12.5 and 15 does not have any of this functionalities.

Comment: In Sybase Online Docs, there are references to EAServer and Unwired platform which looks like some sort of middleware on top of sybase database. I was hoping there are some undocumented features in Sybase that is aligned with Oracle or Sql Server.